# How to measure the performance of Knowledge-Based Systems (KBSs) built with ontology?

Tags: ontology

I have developed an Ontology, and the next step is to build a knowledge-based system (KBS) by using the ontology as the knowledge base. However, I don't how to measure the performance of an ontology-based KBS against traditional computer application or other knowledge-based systems which built using other knowledge representation method. How can I do this? How can I prove that my ontology-based KBS is better than other computer application in some ways?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to understand how you need to post questions in this community. SO is not for to provide ready made working code.  Show some efforts, what you have tried so far, what errors you got, what you want to achieve? That will help others to understand how to support you.

Comment: First you need to define "better", which will depend on your application domain. A generalised definition of "better" is that it can do everything the other can do, and then more. You'll define the scope of "what the other can do" depending on your domain and purpose. So it could be better for sharing, accuracy, reasoning, explaining, outcomes, performance, it's up to you to decide. Then your evaluation method will follow from what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must know my purpose first.